# Is there a way to combine multiple regular expressions for a substring command?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to combine these two regular expressions I am using to convert multi-platform file paths to a URL?

```
@image_file = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host}/#{@image_file.path.sub(/^([a-z]):\//,"")}".sub(/^\//,"")
```

This handles both my Windows and *IX platforms for file path conversion to a URL.  For example, both of the following file path strings are handled properly:

```
 - "c:\users\docs\pictures\image.jpg" goes to "http://localhost/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg"
 - "\home\usr_name\pictures\image.jpg" goes to "http://localhost/usr_name/pictures/image.jpg"
```

I would prefer not to have to use two `sub` calls on a string if there is a way to combine them properly.

Suggestions and feedback from the community welcome!

Comment: The `sub` you currently show doesn't covert the backslash to forward slash like your example shows. But the easiest thing to do is to have two subs in series: `.sub(/^([a-z]:)?/i, "").gsub(/\//,"/")`. The `sub` eliminates the drive letter, and the `gsub` converts the slashes.

Comment: mrbratch, you are correct that the sub doesn't convert the backslash... I tested out what you said in interactive Ruby. Thanks. I am on Windows and have not got around to testing it on a Linux variant I am running. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is `/^([a-z]:)?\//`:

```
"c:/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg".sub(/^([a-z]:)?\//, '')
=> "users/docs/pictures/image.jpg" 
"/home/usr_name/pictures/image.jpg".sub(/^([a-z]:)?\//, '')
=> "home/usr_name/pictures/image.jpg"
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you Uri.  I knew there was a simpler way to do that. I was way over-thinking the regex.

Answer (score 0):

As some background on working with filenames and URLs...

First, Ruby doesn't require you to use reversed-slashes in Windows filenames, so if you're generating them don't bother. Instead, rely on the fact that the IO class knows what OS you're on and will auto-sense the path separator and convert things for you on the fly. This is from [the IO documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:
>
> ```
> "c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
> ```
>
> Our examples here will use the Unix-style forward slashes; File::ALT_SEPARATOR can be used to get the platform-specific separator character.

If you're receiving the paths from another source, this makes it easy to normalize them into something Ruby likes:

```
path = "c:\\users\\docs\\pictures\\image.jpg" # => "c:\\users\\docs\\pictures\\image.jpg"
puts path
# >> c:\users\docs\pictures\image.jpg

path.gsub!(/\\/, '/') if path['\\']
path # => "c:/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg"
puts path
# >> c:/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg
```

For convenience, write a little helper method:

```
def normalize_path(p)
  p.gsub(/\\/, '/')
end

normalize_path("c:\\users\\docs\\pictures\\image.jpg") # => "c:/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg"
normalize_path("/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg") # => "/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg"
```

Ruby's [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html) and [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) classes are very helpful when dealing with paths:

```
foo = normalize_path(path) # => "c:/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg"

File.dirname(foo) # => "c:/users/docs/pictures"
File.basename(foo) # => "image.jpg"
```

and:

```
File.split(foo) # => ["c:/users/docs/pictures", "image.jpg"]
path_to_file, filename = File.split(foo)
path_to_file # => "c:/users/docs/pictures"
filename # => "image.jpg"
```

Alternately there's the Pathname class:

```
require 'pathname'
bar = Pathname.new(foo)
bar.dirname # => #<Pathname:c:/users/docs/pictures>
bar.basename # => #<Pathname:image.jpg>
```

Pathname is an experimental class in Ruby's standard library that wraps up all the convenience methods from File, FileUtils and Dir into one umbrella class. It's worth getting to know:

> The goal of this class is to manipulate file path information in a neater way than standard Ruby provides. The examples below demonstrate the difference.
>
> All functionality from File, FileTest, and some from Dir and FileUtils is included, in an unsurprising way. It is essentially a facade for all of these, and more.

Back to your question...

Ruby's standard library also contains the URI class. It's well tested and is a better way to build URLs than simple string concatenation due to idiosyncrasies that can occur when characters need to be encoded.

```
require 'uri'

url = URI::HTTP.build({:host => 'www.foo.com', :path => foo[/^(?:[a-z]:)?(.+)/, 1]})
url # => #<URI::HTTP:0x007fe91117a438 URL:http://www.foo.com/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg>
```

The [`build`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/HTTP.html#method-c-build) method applies syntax rules to make sure the URL is valid.

If you need it, at this point you can tack on `to_s` to get the stringified version:

```
url.to_s # => "http://www.foo.com/users/docs/pictures/image.jpg"
```